DataDog in Lambda Error handler is undefined
I am currently trying to integrate Datadog into my AWS Lambdas.
In my CI pipeline I call the following:
 - aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $LAMBDA_NAME --environment Variables="{ENV=dev,DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME=TABLENAME,MAILPASSWORD=$MAILPASSWORD,MAILUSER=$MAILUSER,DD_API_KEY=$DD_API_KEY,DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER=users/index.handler}"
 - datadog-ci lambda instrument --function $LAMBDA_NAME --region $AWS_REGION`

Afterwards the following is set as handler entrypoint: /opt/nodejs/node_modules/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler
Now the problem is that the index.js with the handler is in the users/index.js folder.
As variable DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER I set
users/index.handler

Now I have the problem that it throws an error:
{
    ‘errorType": ‘Runtime.ImportModuleError’,
    ‘errorMessage": ‘Error: Cannot find module ‘handler’\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs’,
    ‘stack": [
        ‘Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module ‘handler’’,
        ‘Require stack:’,
        ‘- /var/runtime/index.mjs’,
        ‘ at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)’,
        ‘ at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)’,
        ‘ at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)’,
        ‘ at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1’
    ]
}

If I set the handler directly to users/index.handler, everything works, but then no DataDog. The path is correct. I have downloaded the ZIP and users/index.js is correct.
Do you have any idea what is wrong?
If you need more information, please let me know.
Thank you!

tl;dr - Add the nodeLayerVersion: <number> in your Datadog construct's constructor properties.
Before the fix
I had the exact same error as the OP. My deployments are managed with CDK code:
In code:

handler property set to "index.main"
using the Datadog construct w/ addLambdaFunctions([myLambda])

In AWS:

Lambda "successfully" deployed in AWS
bundled/transpiled file index.js exists, containing main method (matching handler above)
Handler Lambda property set to /path/to/datadog-lambda-js/handler.handler (automagically)
DD_LAMBDA_HANDLER environment var set to index.main (automagically)
Exactly one Lambda Layer (named Datadog-Extension)

Runtime:

Same runtime error: Error: Cannot find module ‘handler’

After the fix
Code changes:

Added the nodeLayerVersion: <number> field & value to the Datadog construct's constructor properties (from the DatadogProps interface)

AWS resource changes:

An additional Lambda Layer (named Datadog-NodeXxx) is added to my Lambda in question

At runtime:

Datadog successfully invokes my index.main handler method

